# Spring Creating a Queue with Domain Objects

Tags: java, spring

I have a requirement wherein i have to create Some Domain Objects like 10 and put them into a queue. The Domain Objects might use other objects(which are loaded using spring).

What is the best way to achieve this.? Should i instantiate the DOmain Objects using new operator and fill the queue or is there a spring feature to accomplish that.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create those domain object by Spring and get them via ApplicationContext in your java source code

Comment: I have to create multiple objects and then put them into a queue. and i wanted to do everything with spring.. Mixed Mode is not preferred :(

Answer (score 0):

You may create some interface like `QueuedDomainObject` without any methods, implement it in every domain object and put them to queue using

```
@Inject
List<QueuedDomainObject> queue;
```